# MUX verilog code

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, multiplexer

Can anyone explain the difference between the two codes below. Both written in Verilog, Xilinx. If someone can explain how the second one works would much appreciate it.

```
module decoder_24(in1, in2, out1, out2, out3, out4);
    input in1,in2;
    output out1,out2,out3,out4;
    assign  out1 =!(!in2&!in1);
    assign  out2 =!(!in2&in1);
    assign  out3 =!(in2&!in1);
    assign  out4 =!(in2&in1);
endmodule

module multiplexer41_4bit(input0, input1, input2, input3, sel0, sel1, out);
    input [3:0] input0,input1,input2,input3;
    input sel0,sel1;
    output [3:0] out;

    //multiplexer0
    multiplexer_41 M41_0(input0[0],input1[0],input2[0],input3[0],sel0,sel1,out[0]);

    //multiplexer1
    multiplexer_41 M41_1(input0[1],input1[1],input2[1],input3[1],sel0,sel1,out[1]);

    //multiplexer2
    multiplexer_41 M41_2(input0[2],input1[2],input2[2],input3[2],sel0,sel1,out[2]);

    //multiplexer0
    multiplexer_41 M41_3(input0[3],input1[3],input2[3],input3[3],sel0,sel1,out[3]);
endmodule
```

Second:

```
case({m_sel2,m_sel1})
    2'b00: m_out = m_in1;   
    2'b01: m_out = m_in2;
    2'b10: m_out = m_in3;    
    2'b11: m_out = m_in4;   
    default: m_out = 1'b0;
endcase
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first module, `decoder_24`, is a decoder. It has 2 inputs and 4 outputs. It asserts exactly one of the outputs, depending on what combinations of inputs is asserted.

Your second module, `multiplexer41_4bit`, is a multiplexer. It has 4 data inputs, 2 select inputs, and one output. The data inputs and the output are each 4 bits wide. Depending on what combination of select lines are asserted, the one of the data inputs is passed through to the output.

How it works, is there's 4 single-bit multiplexers in parallel. Each one is controlled by the select lines, and has its data inputs connected to one bit of each of the 4 data inputs and its output connected to one of the bits of the output. As for how the one-bit multiplexers work, you need to look at the `multiplexer_41` module to find out.

Comment: Thank you. Helpful comment. However still kinda lost you at the end. I think if you try to explain me what the numbers in the brackets mean will get it. for example at the line below what number 3 represents?                                          input0[3]

Comment: When you declare `input [3:0] input0`, you are saying that `input0` is a bus with 4 wires. The individual wires are `input0[0]`, `input0[1]`, etc.

Comment: @sotiris That's the index of the bit that you're passing (zero based of course).

Answer (score 0):

> If someone can explain how the second one works would much appreciate it.

```
case({m_sel2,m_sel1})
    2'b00: m_out = m_in1;   
    2'b01: m_out = m_in2;
    2'b10: m_out = m_in3;    
    2'b11: m_out = m_in4;   
    default: m_out = 1'b0;
endcase
```

Lets consider, that all signals (m_sel2, m_sel1, m_out, m_in1, m_in2, m_in3, m_in4) are 1 bit long.

Tnen `{m_sel2,m_sel1}` - is concatenation of two signals m_sel2 and m_sel1. 
If m_sel2 = 1'b0 and m_sel1 = 1'b1, then {m_sel2,m_sel1} will be equal to 2'b01.

Case statement synthesizes into a multiplexer. If think for a while about how case works - you will find, that it is pretty much the same as mux.

As for the realization: Case statement is  a **Behavioral Statement**, and it must be inside **Procedural Block**. So I added some minor code:

```
module mux_4x1(m_sel2, m_sel1, m_in1, m_in2, m_in3, m_in4, m_out);
    input m_sel2, m_sel1;
    input m_in1, m_in2, m_in3, m_in4;
    output reg m_out;

    always @(m_sel2, m_sel1, m_in1, m_in2, m_in3, m_in4) 
    begin 
        case ({m_sel2, m_sel1})
            2'b00: m_out <= m_in1;   
            2'b01: m_out <= m_in2;
            2'b10: m_out <= m_in3;    
            2'b11: m_out <= m_in4;   
            default: m_out <= 1'b0;   
        endcase;
    end
endmodule
```

So I went a little bit further and made simple project in Altera Quartus II. I think, that with Xilinx FPGA there will not be much differences.

After building a project we can see the result in a rtl-viewer.

[image]

Compilation Summary tells us, mux project uses 2 4-input LUTs. For better understanding about how mux is created on LUTs, you can look at this:

[image]

Here LUTs functions are represented as scheme.

I hope that I did not confuse You even more!