# What do square brackets represent in verilog?

Tags: verilog

Can anybody help? I know it must be very simple but I am still confused with the following:

M41_1(input0[1],input1[1],input2[1],input3[1],sel0,sel1,out[1]);

What do the numbers in the square brackets represent?

Comment: I'm a VHDL guy, but typically brackets and parentheses indicate reference to a particular bit. That looks like some kind of concatenation operator. I'll let someone that is familiar with Verilog answer.

Comment: This has to be in some kind of manual or basic tutorial, no?

Comment: @dext0rb - I was thinking the same thing, but then I went to my [favorite tutorial](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/) but realized that I couldn't find a clear definition of this after 10 minutes of looking. Anyway sotiris please be careful not to ask too many questions too quickly, it makes you look lazy. You should try following some tutorials first, or you'll end up with a bad reputation.

Answer (score 2):

The `[ ]` is a **part select**.

The term `input0[1]` means: take the second from the lowest wire of bus `input0`.

So if `input0` is a 4-bit bus, then `input0[1]` is a 1-bit wire formed from that bus.

So if : `wire [3:0] input0 = 4'b0010;`

then `input0[1]` is equal to 1'b1.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your [earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58856/mux-verilog-code), when you declare

```
input [3:0] input0;
```

you are saying that input0 is a bus with 4 wires. The individual wires are `input0[0]`, `input0[1]`, etc.

As Tim says, this construct is formally called "part select" in Verilog. You can do more than just take individual wires. For example, if you want to take the two low-order wires as a bus, for example, you could use `input0[1:0]`.

The code in your question is not well-formed Verilog on its own. The complete line from your previous question was

```
 multiplexer_41 M41_0(input0[0],input1[0],input2[0],input3[0],sel0,sel1,out[0]);
```

`multiplexer_41` is the name of another module, which you are instantiating with this line of code. `M41_0` is the name of the instance you are creating. `input0[0]` and so on are the signals from your module that you are connecting to the inputs and outputs of the multiplexer_41 named M41_0.

But without the name of another module, as you show it in this question, the Verilog compiler will have no idea what you are trying to instantiate.